# How to limit the background downloads of a PFFile - Parse Framework

Tags: ios, background, parse-platform, limit, pffile

Im using the Parse Framework for developing an app that loads images from the Parse Server, im using the Parse method:

```
PFFile *file = object[@"file"];
[file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            ...
}
```

but i want to limit the number of files getting in the background

Any idea how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: This code should get one file associated with name "file". So if you receive number of files in this request, perhaps you've combined number of files to one NSData object, but it's hard to believe in that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your retrieval of the file from Parse.com in an `NSOperation`, and submit them to an `NSOperationQueue`. You should then set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` on the queue to be the maximum concurrent file download operations, and you should have the concurrent download throttling that you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this function in a singleton Class, and create a global variable, a counter, and each time your user pass on this function you increase the counter.

Besides, before the function execution check the counter number, and do it or not.

For the case the user close the app, you can create a plist for storage this information.

Hope it helps.